# Integrating CiviCRM in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to CiviCRM and I have just installed it in WordPress. Am having problems with the integration. I would like users to register to become members, once they registered, they should be redirected to their profile page where they can view their dashboard which consists of their contributions and membership status. I am not able to achieve this at all. Secondly, when deploying a form, they don't show the labels. So if someone is filling a form, they won't know if the field is asking for email or phone number. I really need help with this;  I am volunteering for a charity organisation who is looking to put their membership structure in place desperately.

Comment: First it helps if you tell the forum what version of CiviCRM you are using. Second, you are asking many questions in one. It would be better to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

As ErikH said you do have several questions here. I would suggest taking a look at the following links to the User Guide. This will help clear up the process for you.

Defining Member Types: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/
Membership Sign up: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/online-membership-sign-up/

You should also look at the following as these are involved in creating online member signups:

Profiles: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/

Price Sets: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/complex-event-fees/#price-sets

You may also need to utilize a few WordPress plugins to achieve what you are looking for. If you have more specific questions please post here.

Hope this helps!